# Bedeutung von "Ich trank viel zu kaltes Bier"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Ich trank viel zu kaltes Bier.

Kann es heißen, dass

> (a) Ich trank Bier, das viel zu kalt war.

oder

> (b) Ich trank viel Bier, das zu kalt war.

oder beides?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Interessanter Satz. (a) und (b) sind beide möglich, aber (a) ist viel wahrscheinlicher. Man müßte viel prosodische Arbeit leisten, um einem Hörer verläßlich den Sinn (b) zu vermitteln. Selbst die schriftliche Variante (mit Komma vor 'zu') wirkt unüblich.

Comment: was auch immer ["prosodisch"](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosodisch) heißt... hat mal jemand einen Thesaurus? - Satzübergreifender Sinn? oder vielleicht eher: Kontext!

Comment: Die [Prosodie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosodie) ist ein Teil der Aussprache. Sie umfasst Dinge wie die Satzmelodie und soll unter anderem die Struktur und Intention des Satzes dem Empfänger durch Pausen und Betonung klarer machen.

Answer (score 1):

(a) stimmt, aber (b) nicht.

Das Wort `viel` im Satz `Ich trank viel zu kaltes Bier.` bezieht sich auf `kaltes` (Eigenschaft des Bieres) und nicht auf die Menge.

(b) ist zwar nicht falsch, aber im originalen Satz ist nicht ersichtlich, um wie viel Bier es sich handelt.

Comment: Warum ist die b-Interpretation nicht möglich? Wie auch Kilian schrieb, teile ich die Meinung, dass beide Interpretationen möglich sind.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist (b) falsch, weil im Satz "Ich trank viel zu kaltes Bier." nicht klar ist, wie viel Bier getrunken wird. Es kann ein Schluck gewesen sein, oder 10 Flaschen.

Comment: Es ist in dem Satz "Ich trank viel Bier." auch nicht klar ob ich ein Schluck oder 10 Flaschen für "viel" halte. Der Satz ist trotzdem nicht falsch.

Comment: Ja, nicht "falsch" aber trotzdem sehr merkwürdig. Wenn jemand sagt, er trink viel Bier, ich frage wie viel, und er sagt "nur einen Schluck", dann ist das doch ziemlich merkwürdig.

Answer (score 0):

Ich glaube nicht, dass (b) in diesem Fall richtig sein kann. Ich denke, dass ein Komma eingefügt werden müsste. Ohne Komma kann sich das viel meiner Meinung nach nur auf "zu kalt" beziehen, nicht aber auf das Bier selbst.

Answer (score -1):

Wie bereits bemerkt ist Variante (a) richtig. Um Variante (b) auszudrücken, würde man folgenden Satz verwenden.

> Ich trank zu viel kaltes Bier.

Comment: Das ist aber nicht genau das Gleiche wie `Ich trank viel Bier, das zu kalt war.`